# How to add external training in chatterbot?

Tags: training, python, chat-bots

I created a very simple bot to learn how to use chatterbot. This library already comes with a training, but I wanted extra training with an import of a corpus in Portuguese that I found in github.

```
from chatterbot import ChatBot

bot = Futaba(
"Terminal",
storage_adapter="chatterbot.storage.SQLStorageAdapter",
logic_adapters=[
"chatterbot.logic.MathematicalEvaluation",
"chatterbot.logic.TimeLogicAdapter",
"chatterbot.logic.BestMatch"
],

input_adapter="chatterbot.input.TerminalAdapter",
output_adapter="chatterbot.output.TerminalAdapter",
database_uri="../database.db"
)

print("Type something to begin...")

while True:
    try:
        bot_input = bot.get_response(None)
    except (KeyboardInterrupt, EOFError, SystemExit):
        break
```

That's all I have.

How can I import this corpus into my chatbot?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's not really about AI, but about an implementation detail with a particular software package, which happens to be on an AI-related topic.

Comment: Wow, but then I do not understand. If I ask questions about developing a chatbot in a programming forum the question is closed because it refers to AI. If I ask in an AI forum close for not being on IA.

Comment: This seems to me to be about a specific piece of software. To answer that question you need no expertise in AI, so that's my reasoning. I have worked with/in AI for about 20+ years, and I have no clue how to answer your question.  I don't even know what library you are talking about, so I cannot look up the documentation for it.

Comment: Chatterbot for python

Comment: Programming issues are off-topic here. Please, read https://ai.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic for more details and to understand which questions are on-topic here. If you have a programming issue, the best place to ask your question is Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure if this is the right one, but according to the [documentation](https://github.com/gunthercox/ChatterBot) you need to create a trainer for it:

```
from chatterbot.trainers import ChatterBotCorpusTrainer

# Create a new trainer for the chatbot
trainer = ChatterBotCorpusTrainer(chatbot)

# Train based on the english corpus
trainer.train("chatterbot.corpus.english")
```

Instead of "chatterbot.corpus.english" you obviously choose your own training data.

Comment: Basically, I just need to put my corpus, put in the chatbot folder and import on that page?

Comment: That's how I understand it. Not sure what format the corpus needs to be in -- you might have to look at the other example data sets.